# Is there a reason my vba macro to transfer an excel sheet to a pdf doesn't show everything?

Tags: excel, vba, export-to-pdf

This is the code for a button I have on my userform to change the active sheet in my workbook to a pdf. I'm wondering why not everything in my excel sheet is showing. The first 6-7 pages of my excel sheet show perfectly fine, and it's one or two sections at the end of my sheet that show portions, or nothing at all

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
    Dim strFile As String
    Dim invoiceRng As Range
    Dim pdfFile As String

    'Setting range to be printed
    Set invoiceRng = Range("A1:D850")
    'setting file name with a time stamp.
    strFile = "Checklist" & "_" & Format(Now(), "yyyymmdd_hhmmss") & ".pdf"
    'setting the name. The resultent pdf will be saved where the main file exists.
    pdfFile = ThisWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & strFile
    invoiceRng.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
    Filename:=pdfFile, _
    Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
    IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
    IgnorePrintAreas:=True, _
    OpenAfterPublish:=True
End Sub
```

Comment: Check your print area. Not sure if that has an effect to `ExportAsFixedFormat`: [Set or clear a print area on a worksheet](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/set-or-clear-a-print-area-on-a-worksheet-27048af8-a321-416d-ba1b-e99ae2182a7e?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) and make sure everything that you want to export is in that range `Range("A1:D850")`

Comment: I've been trying to play around with that, and it's only two specific sections, and I'm not sure why they don't show sometimes, or do show sometimes. Someone had suggested I try looking into a acrobat library, but I'm a vba novice, so this is all new to me